# How to use CodingKeys for enums conforming to Codable Protocol?

Tags: ios, enums, swift4, codable

I have an `EmailVerificationStatus` enum with an associated type of `String` that conforms to the `Codable` protocol:

```
enum EmailVerificationStatus: String, Codable {
    case unverified
    case verified
}
```

The webservice I am working with sends those cases in uppercase (`UNVERIFIED` / `VERIFIED`). How can I use the `CodingKeys` enumeration to map that difference? Something like the following does not work:

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case unverified = "UNVERIFIED"
    case verified = "VERIFIED"
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok. That was simple. No `CodingKeys` needed:

```
enum EmailVerificationStatus: String, Codable {
    case verified = "VERIFIED"
    case unverified = "UNVERIFIED"
}
```

Comment: I've been using `Codable`s since they were introduced, but ran into this problem, too, and I can't believe I didn't think of this. I've been beating my head on the wall for a couple hours.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually do it:

```
struct EmailVerificationStatus: String, Codable {
    var unverified: String
    var verified: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case unverified = "UNVERIFIED"
        case verified = "VERIFIED"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use struct for the Email... type and nest the enum CodingKeys inside your struct. CodingKeys allows you to map your struct variables with your source data cases (from webservice).

```
struct EmailVerificationStatus: String, Codable {
        var unverified: String
        var verified: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case unverified = "UNVERIFIED"
            case verified = "VERIFIED"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that is helpful when your enum has associated values is to put the `Codable` compliance into an extension and then it will not complain about you implementing the CodingKeys enum.

Something like this:

```swift
enum EmailVerificationStatus: String {
    case unverified
    case verified(email:String)
}

extension EmailVerificationStatus: Codable {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case unverified = "UNVERIFIED"
    case verified = "VERIFIED"
  }
}
```